# how to get authorization code to my wp app for google authentication?

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

In my WP7.5 app, I have redirect the user to google web page where is asked to giving the app permissions to access to his account, user click yes, but it redirects to a page where there is the code and user is supossed to copy/paste that to my app.

The Response is
Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:
4/3oHAHtqSk1CqA3S8HlEsuQRaE08e.4nCBpXhR-R8WgrKXntQAax02U4CwcgI - Auth code

I want to, when user press ok, return to my app with that code, is there any way to do that?

-SheikAbdullah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Browser control, here's a great CodeProject article on how to do it:

[Google OAuth2 on Windows Phone](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321291/Google-OAuth2-on-Windows-Phone)